# Need to enable restart button on GUI Ubuntu Server 22.04 + XFCE4 + sddm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, ubuntu-22.04

Currently I have 2 users: root and gigi.
gigi is not sudoer and cannot be, BUT, needs to have the possibility to reboot the server through 2 ways.

1º -> through terminal. I edited visudo and now I can apply a sudo reboot on terminal wihtout any issue.

2º -> through GUI. The button appears but greyed.

I given permissions to gigi to reach /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/50-restart.pkla

50-restart.pkla content:

```
[Allow gigi restart]
Identity=unix-user:gigi
Action=org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.restart
ResultAny=yes
```

With this file I supposed to enable the button, but nothing happens.